# Claiming of all patentable material in patent

Tags: patentability, scope

My patent may have several types of 
new inventions within it.
If I get a patent on my one invention 
do I have some type of patent rights over 
those other novel features in the invention 
or do I have to claim each one individually 
for special rights ?

Answer (score 1):

The protection is defined by - and **only** by - the claims.

You can talk about god, the world, your neighbours dog, apple and the blue LED in your patent specification, but that will not grant you any kind of protection.

The grant of a patent is primarily decided by the novelty and inventiveness of it's claims and the wording of these (the claims that are granted) decides what is protected.

Nobody may use, sell, etc. anything that falls under the literal **scope of the claims** of a granted patent without a license. *Equivalents* are protected to some extent (for further information research "doctrine of equivalents").

Anything else that appears only in the description **does not** entitle you to **any protection**.

If you do want to try to obtain protection for other material described in the application, you can pursue claims directed to that material in a continuation application or a divisional application. Any continuing application need to be filed while the parent application is still pending (i.e., before the parent goes abandoned or issues as a patent).

It should be noted that the claims need to be supported by the specification and that non-standard terms used in the claims need to be defined. Also, while what is protected is defined by the claims, any additional information disclosed in the patent becomes prior art and can be used to keep others (or even the original inventor) from obtaining further patents.

Comment: So as long as it is novel "makes sense " and is in the claims then I have rights over each novel element of my patent ???

Comment: So lang as it is in the claims **after** the grant of the patent you have protection rights. For it to be there, the patent with the claims needs to be granted and for that to happen, all claimed inventions have to fulfill the requirements (novelty, inventiveness/inventive step and usefullness/industrial applicability).

Comment: The claims in a granted patent often are not the same as in the application exactly for this reason - maybe the examiner thinks a claim is not inventive, so the applicant submits a narrowed claim to *try again*.

Comment: @DonQuiKong  The claims do need to be supported by the specification. Mom standard terms in claims can be defined in the specification.

Comment: Yes of course, I was merely talking about the scope of the final patent and trying not to go deeper into the specific requierements for a grant. If that wasn't clear - *What eric said* For a patent to be granted, the claims have to fulfill certain (formal and substantial) requierements.

Comment: @DonQuiKong  I think you should add a little bit to your answer covering my earlier comment and also that while only the claims provide protection, the rest of the specification can count as prior art to keep others or the inventor from getting further patents.

Comment: I was trying not to overcomplicate it, but maybe you are right. I made the answer community wiki so go ahead and edit it (I'm going to sleep now and I'll have forgotten it by tomorrow I bet, if not and I find time, I'll add some more words myself.)

Comment: @DonQuiKong  I added a brief paragraph. Feel free to edit it if you don't fully agree.

Comment: It's a good addition, thx

Comment: You may want to point out that other inventions can be pursued in continuing patent applications if there are indeed multiple inventions described in the application.

Comment: @CanisNebula feel free to edit/suggest an edit yourself, that's why I made the answer community wiki, lowering the reputation needed to edit it.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't know that was possible. I'm still new here.

Comment: @CanisNebula welcome to ask patents then. To be fair, community wikis are rare. Suggesting an edit is possible for every post.